# how to parse Xml file through Linux

Tags: java, linux, unix, hadoop

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>pass</value>
  <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>pass`enter code here`</value>
  <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
```

how can we get javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName -pass and 
               javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword -pass

Answer (score 1):

You could try [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)

```
The xmllint program parses one or more XML files, specified on the command line 
as xmlfile. It prints various types of output, depending upon the options 
selected. It is useful for detecting errors both in XML code and 
in the XML parser itself.
```

It allows you select elements in the XML doc by xpath, using the --pattern option.

I have just give you the method now how to use it and get required data is your responsibility.

if you face any problem post it.

It's installed by default on Ubuntu.

Comment: i am new to linux ,can u pls give more light on xmllint -xmllint --shell testxml.xml  i just got first we have to open our xml file in this shell . then how we can parse and how i can take name = value, can u plase share your mail id

Comment: how we can take javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName =pass and javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=value because i have to take this output in java program and then have to do further process .....Pls help me

Comment: Is it compulsory to fetch those element using linux commands ? if no then `xom` is the best suites you. it's so easy and reliable.

Comment: yes that is compulsory because i want to pick url , username and password from my xml file

Comment: and where you will have to pass that credentials ?